# Unresolved dependencies path for SBT project in IntelliJ

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt, spark-streaming

I'm using IntelliJ to develop Spark application. I'm following this [instruction](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-scala/wiki/%5BSBT%5D-How-to-use-provided-libraries-in-run-configurations) on how to make intellij work nicely with SBT project.

As my whole team is using IntelliJ so we can just modify build.sbt but we got this unresolved dependencies error

Error:Error while importing SBT project:

```
[info] Resolving org.apache.thrift#libfb303;0.9.2 ...
[info] Resolving org.apache.spark#spark-streaming_2.10;2.1.0 ...
[info] Resolving org.apache.spark#spark-streaming_2.10;2.1.0 ...
[info] Resolving org.apache.spark#spark-parent_2.10;2.1.0 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-lang#jline;2.10.6 ...
[info] Resolving org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.4 ...
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: sparrow-to-orc#sparrow-to-orc_2.10;0.1: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]
[warn]  Note: Unresolved dependencies path:
[warn]      sparrow-to-orc:sparrow-to-orc_2.10:0.1
[warn]        +- mainrunner:mainrunner_2.10:0.1-SNAPSHOT
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run 'last mainRunner/:ssExtractDependencies' for the full output.
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run 'last mainRunner/:update' for the full output.
[error] (mainRunner/:ssExtractDependencies) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: sparrow-to-orc#sparrow-to-orc_2.10;0.1: not found
[error] (mainRunner/:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: sparrow-to-orc#sparrow-to-orc_2.10;0.1: not found
[error] Total time: 47 s, completed Jun 10, 2017 8:39:57 AM
```

And this is my build.sbt

```
name := "sparrow-to-orc"

version := "0.1"

scalaVersion := "2.11.8"

lazy val sparkDependencies = Seq(
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.1.0",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "2.1.0",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-hive" % "2.1.0",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming" % "2.1.0"
)

libraryDependencies += "com.amazonaws" % "aws-java-sdk" % "1.7.4"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-aws" % "2.7.1"

libraryDependencies ++= sparkDependencies.map(_ % "provided")

lazy val mainRunner = project.in(file("mainRunner")).dependsOn(RootProject(file("."))).settings(
  libraryDependencies ++= sparkDependencies.map(_ % "compile")
)

assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly := {
  case PathList("org","aopalliance", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.last
  case PathList("javax", "inject", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.last
  case PathList("javax", "servlet", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.last
  case PathList("javax", "activation", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.last
  case PathList("org", "apache", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.last
  case PathList("com", "google", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.last
  case PathList("com", "esotericsoftware", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.last
  case PathList("com", "codahale", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.last
  case PathList("com", "yammer", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.last
  case "about.html" => MergeStrategy.rename
  case "META-INF/ECLIPSEF.RSA" => MergeStrategy.last
  case "META-INF/mailcap" => MergeStrategy.last
  case "META-INF/mimetypes.default" => MergeStrategy.last
  case "plugin.properties" => MergeStrategy.last
  case "log4j.properties" => MergeStrategy.last
  case "overview.html" => MergeStrategy.last
  case x =>
    val oldStrategy = (assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly).value
    oldStrategy(x)
}

run in Compile <<= Defaults.runTask(fullClasspath in Compile, mainClass in (Compile, run), runner in (Compile, run))
```

If I don't have this line then the program works fine

```
lazy val mainRunner = project.in(file("mainRunner")).dependsOn(RootProject(file("."))).settings(
  libraryDependencies ++= sparkDependencies.map(_ % "compile")
)
```

But then i won't be able to run the application inside IntelliJ as spark dependencies won't be included in the classpath.

Comment: `sparrow-to-orc#sparrow-to-orc_2.10;0.1` seems to be your own program, but with another scala version. Not sure where that is coming from, but it's a smell that something is wrongly configured.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. The solution is to set the Scala version in the `mainRunner` to be the same as the one declared at the top of the `build.sbt` file:

```
lazy val mainRunner = project.in(file("mainRunner")).dependsOn(RootProject(file("."))).settings(
    libraryDependencies ++= sparkDependencies.map(_ % "compile"),
    scalaVersion := "2.11.8"
)
```

Good luck!